# Windows Server 2022, IIS 10, and SSL - Website is not loading

Tags: iis, windows-server-2022

When my website is installed on Windows server 2016 and 2019 it works perfectly. On Windows Sever 2022 I get an error of "This site can’t be reached The connection was reset" but if I go to IIS -> SSL -> and change client certificates to Ignore instead of Accept or I can go to IIS -> bindings -> port 443 -> select disable TSL 1.3 over TCP it loads up correctly

Can someone explain why this is happening? What Can I do? I don't want to do any of those options

Comment: What web browser (and its version/OS) do you use?

Comment: It is Chrome and Edge (the latest versions/windows server 2022), I am seeing the same issue in both of them

Comment: You might run a report to reveal more about the server certificate, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html

Comment: There are many reasons for this error, look in the event log for errors (in the security section you often see https related errors).

Comment: There is no errors in the Event viewer

Comment: You can check the console in chrome, or use the failed request trace, or try using Fiddler for detailed error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue. I had added the Public IPs to the NIC in Azure that was assigned to my VM, I also added the IPs to the VMs NIC (via IPv4 properties on the Ethernet connection) however the issue for me was only resolved once I added the Internal IPs to the VM as well and assigned those to the IIS node under the Bindings section. It turns out that Azure only forwards traffic to your VM using the Internal IP addresses which is why the connection would time out (because my VM was not listening on those IPs)